# How do I force to input before termination?

Tags: c++

Here is an excerpt of my code, where the problem lies.

```
    long long user_largest_plus;
    long long user_largest_minus;
    cout << "Input the largest+1 in decimal: " << endl;
    cin >> user_largest_plus;
//cout << endl;


   // cout << "Input the largest-1 in decimal: " << endl;
    cin >> user_largest_minus;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "In decimal plus: " << user_largest_plus;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "In decimal minus: " << user_largest_minus;
```

As soon as I input 9223372036854775808  to `user_largest_plus`, the execution would terminate. That is, I wouldn't be able to input for `user_largest_minus`. 
I am using Code::Blocks, MinGW compiler.

Is it because I just overflowed the variable, and the error triggered this termination. Any work around?

By the way, that number is `2^63 - 1`, maximum number that I can store.

Thanks

Comment: Don't make users add or subtract one; make the computer do it.

Comment: oh right, use `LLONG_MAX` in `<climits>`.  Because long long _cannot hold_ 9223372036854775808.  That is 2^63, not 2^63-1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing

```
cin >> user_largest_plus;
```

with

```
if( !( cin >> user_largest_plus ) ) {
    user_largest_plus = 0;
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Bad input. Using zero instead\n";
}
```

When the input text is not a valid `long long`, two interesting things happen:

- `user_largest_plus` is never set, and
- the [`bad`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/bad/) bit is set in `cin`.

The provided code sets *some* value to `user_largest_plus` to avoid undefined behavior, and clears the bad bit, so `cin` can still be used.

Comment: You may want to print error: To help with spotting the problem.

Comment: although I would replace `if` with `while`, personally

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is because the entered number is to big (and to prevent bugs when the user enters `APPLE` as the size, you should do something like this:

```
string user_largest_plus_string;
long long user_largest_plus;
cout << "Input the largest+1 in decimal: " << endl;
cin >> user_largest_plus_string;
user_largest_plus = atoi(user_largest_plus_string.c_str());
if (user_largest_plus == 0)
    throw std::runtime_error("User entered something besides a number!");
cout << "largest+1 is now " << user_largest_plus << "." << endl;
```